# jquery slidetoggle expands and collapses straight away

Tags: jquery

Please see here: http://www.wunderwedding.com/weddingvenues/search

On the left side there's a filter 'show more cities...'

When it's clicked I want to show more cities. But right now when it's clicked the box expands and IMMEDIATELY collapses again. I dont know what Im doing wrong.
This is the code for show/hide:

```
$("#toggle_cities").click(function () {
    if ($("#facets_city").is(":visible")) {
        $("#toggle_cities").text('toon meer steden...');
    }
    else {
        $("#toggle_cities").text('toon minder steden...');
    }
    $("#facets_city").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Looks fine to me! Are you sure you don't have any code that's interfering with the click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click event subscribed by jQuery 1.4.2 (trigger event)
Function defined on line 252 in _genfunc-1.6.1.js

```
function () {
    if ($("#facets_city").is(":visible")) {
        $("#toggle_cities").text('toon meer steden...');
    }
    else {
        $("#toggle_cities").text('toon minder steden...');
    }
    $("#facets_city").slideToggle("slow");
}
```

And:

click event subscribed by jQuery 1.4.2 (trigger event)
Function defined on line 61 in myfuncs_en.js

```
function () {
    if ($("#facets_city").is(":visible")) {
        $("#toggle_cities").text('show more cities...');
    }
    else {
        $("#toggle_cities").text('show less cities...');
    }
    $("#facets_city").slideToggle("slow");
}
```

You have two event handlers. I guess one for english and one for...err..Dutch?

P.S. the Visual Event bookmarklet is really useful for problems like this: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: indeed dutch. +1! I did search for that too, but didn't find it!

Comment: That was it! My god, I would have never found that. Thx for the Visual Event link too! :)

Answer (score 2):

It could be event bubbling so the click happens twice.

```
$("#toggle_cities").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops event propagation
    if ($("#facets_city").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).html('toon meer steden...');
    }
    else {
        $(this).html('toon minder steden...');
    }
    $("#facets_city").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: wow. I really want to know if this works. +1 for thinking of a intended cause. (If you know what I mean. My English is not that great. )

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/rjgew/), it's working without propagation, I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks and yes I got what did you mean and your English is good enough. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the event toggle. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

```
$("#toggle_cities").toggle(function () {
    $(this).text('toon meer steden...');
    $("#facets_city").slideDown("slow");
},function(){
    $(this).text('toon minder steden...');
    $("#facets_city").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when i'm looking in the scripts-tab of the web inspector, i see three jquery-scripts embedded in the page. kick out two of them and then try it again.

and imho it can't be a propagation-issue as the #facets_city-element is no child-element of the #toggle_cities-element.